# I have set timezone in Heroku, but nothing changes

Tags: django, heroku, timezone

I am developing an app in Django and I have pushed it on Heroku. It returns the current time when the user do certain things.

In local, there is no problem. On Heroku, there is a two hours difference with respect to my timezone datetime (Berlin/Europe)

I have set Heroku timezone as "Europe/Berlin" by typing in my command prompt:

```
heroku config:add TZ="Europe/Berlin"
heroku config:set TZ="Europe/Berlin"
```

, and it seems it got it:

```
heroku config:get TZ
```

> Europe/Berlin

I waited two days because I expected the server needed to update, but the problem still remains.

What is wrong and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by substituting, in `settings.py`:

```
TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'
```

with

```
TIME_ZONE = 'Europe/Berlin'
```